# Can reactjs refresh/reload its props if the clicked link is not owned by reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, backbone.js, react-router-dom

Title seems confusing because it is. So I have a laravel and its own Reactjs stuff, lets call it `reactA`.

So I have another JS that is another react, lets call it `reactB`, doing its on thing and render on a <`div`>. Which uses requirejs to get all the js and using backbonejs to do the routing.

And I have manage to 'put' `reactB` pages into `reactA`, where `reactA` is like the main page with a `Nav` on the left hand side and content on the right. The `Nav` consist of link of both `reactA` and `reactB`. When a `reactB` link is clicked a blank <`div`> will be rendered and `reactB` will render its stuff to said <`div`>.

The situation is like this, whenever the `Nav` (owned by `reactA`) link is pressed, seems to me (correct me if im wrong) that only `reactA` `props` and `states` is updated and not in `reactB`. Which as a result, the `reactB's` react-router-dom stuff will not be updated (useLocation,useSearchParams etc). I found out about this because I have `reactB` print the `this.props.pathname` while press the `Nav` link and sees that the pathname is not updated.

Now to by pass this situation I will do a `windows.location.reload` when a `reactB` link is clicked then `reactB` will load its content no problem. But the web page will be slow because everything is reloaded.

I was wondering if there is a way for `reactB` to reload all its props and states without a full page reload?

Note that `reactA` and `reactB` share a very different code so to merge it would likely be a whole rewrite of the code.

Comment: are reactA and reactB separate react projects? Or are you talking about components? Much better to post your code instead of use here guessing your code and giving imaginary answers.

Comment: If app A and app B are each using their own RRD router, then no, they operate independently, the page reload after navigation events in A will "synchronize" B.

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth yes, they are separate projects. I don't what code should I post because there are no errors, its more of a behavior problem I am finding a way to solve.

Comment: @DrewReese is there a way to have app B reload its props without reloading the whole page? If appB is a .js file can I re-run it? I have tried reload them with react-helmet but seems like they didnt run even if I re-add the .js scripts.

Comment: Maybe a web socket where B can subscribe to A and listen for an emitted navigation event from A and trigger the component rendering B's router to rerender.